# Input date in react doesn't read default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my react app and I have problem with input type date. The app is a book management system and if I want to edit a book, I expect all the inputs to get as default values their current values. It works for every input except the date. I mean - it sees the current date even if I click to change the date, it does have the current date, but in the form it doesn't show, it's like this: `dd-mm-rrrr`

My input code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import BooksForm from './BooksForm';
import {Button, Form} from "react-bootstrap";
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import {AiOutlineWarning} from "react-icons/ai";

const EditBook = (props) => {


    const axios=require('axios')
    const [book,setBook] = useState({
        title:  props.location.title ? props.location.title : '',
        author:  props.location.author ? props.location.author : '',
        genre: props.location.genre ? props.location.genre : '',
        release_date: props.location.release_date ? props.location.release_date : '',
        description: props.location.description ? props.location.description : '',
        image_url: props.location.image_url ? props.location.image_url: ''



    })

    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('')

    const { title,
        author,
        genre,
        release_date,
        description,
        image_url,
        rating_count} = book;

    const handleOnEdit = (event) => {
        console.log(event)
        event.preventDefault();
        const values = [
            title,
            author,
            genre,
            release_date,
            description,
            image_url
        ];
        let errorMessage = '';

        const allFieldsFilled = values.every((field) => {
            const value = `${field}`.trim();
            return value !== '' && value !== '0' && value !== undefined;
        });

        if (allFieldsFilled) {
            if (new Date(release_date) > new Date()) {
                errorMessage='Data nie może być starsza niż dzisiejsza'
                setErrorMessage(errorMessage)
            }
            else {

                const book = {

                    title,
                    author,
                    genre,
                    release_date,
                    description,
                    image_url

                };
                event.preventDefault()
                axios.put('http://localhost:5000/api/book/'+props.location.id,book);
            }
        } else {
            errorMessage = 'Please fill out all the fields.';
        }
        setErrorMessage(errorMessage);
    };



    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        const name = e.target.name
        const value = e.target.value
        setBook((prev) => ({...prev, [name]: value}));

    }


    const data = props.location.release_date
    function formatDate(date) {
        let d = new Date(date),
            month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
            day = '' + d.getDate(),
            year = d.getFullYear();

        if (month.length < 2)
            month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2)
            day = '0' + day;

        return [year, month, day].join('-');
    }


    const dataDobra = formatDate(data)
    console.log(dataDobra)
    return (
    <div className="form">
        {errorMessage && <p className="errorMsg"><AiOutlineWarning />{errorMessage}</p>}
            <Form onSubmit={handleOnEdit}>


                <Form.Group controlId="nazwa">
                    <Form.Label>Wprowadź tytuł książki</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control className="control-input" type="text" name="title" defaultValue={props.location.title} placeholder="Tu edytuj tytuł" onChange={handleInputChange} />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="autor">
                    <Form.Label>Wprowadź autora książki</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control className="control-input" type="text" name="author" defaultValue={props.location.author} placeholder="Tu edytuj autora" onChange={handleInputChange} />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="genre">
                    <Form.Label>Wprowadź gatunek książki</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control className="control-input" type="text" name="genre" defaultValue={props.location.genre} placeholder="Tu edytuj gatunek" onChange={handleInputChange} />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="releaseDate">
                    <Form.Label>Wprowadź datę powstania książki</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control className="control-input" type="date" name="release_date" value={props.location.release_date} placeholder="Tu edytuj datę powstania" onChange={handleInputChange} />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="description">
                    <Form.Label>Wprowadź opis książki</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control className="control-input" type="text" name="description" defaultValue={props.location.description} placeholder="Tu zmień opis" size="30" onChange={handleInputChange} />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="imageurl">
                    <Form.Label>Wprowadź adres URL do zdjęcia książki</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control className="control-input" type="text" name="image_url" defaultValue={props.location.image_url} placeholder="Tu zmień adres do zdjęcia" size="30" onChange={handleInputChange} />
                </Form.Group>



                <Button type="submit" variant="primary" className="submitButton bookButtons">Submit</Button>
                <NavLink to="/"><Button variant="info" onClick={props.location.onEdit}>Don't edit</Button></NavLink>





            </Form>
    </div>
    );
};

export default EditBook;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
This one works for me

```
export default function App() {

  const defaultValue="2020-06-06";
  
  const handleInputChange =(e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form.Control
        className="control-input"
        type="date"
        name="release_date"
        placeholder="Here edit the release date"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: But the default date shouldn't be today's date, but the date, that is currently set to a book.

Comment: I fixed it, but the problem is now that if I don't correct the date and I submit, it makes day-1, so if the release date is 06.06.2021 and if I don't edit the date and I submit, the date turns into 05.06.2021 (the same happens if I use your solution)

Answer (score 0):

Note that you need to have controlled components if you want your user to react with your code and this happens by defining state. Another thing to point out is that you need to pass the initial amount of state which comes from your props through useEffect. So, your code would be something as below:

```
export default function App(props) {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

  useEffect(() => {
    setDate(props.location.release_date)
  }, [])

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setDate(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form.Group controlId="releaseDate">
        <Form.Label>Write a release date here</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control 
          className="control-input" 
          type="date" name="release_date" 
          value={date} 
          placeholder="Here edit the release date" 
          onChange={handleInputChange} 
        />
      </Form.Group>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's not the case, I have all of these things. The thing is that if the default value is shown correctly and if I don't edit it and submit, it changes the day, by decrementing it by one.

Comment: Can you share a sample of your code? A more complete version? to see how you've defined the handleInputchange function and how you have passed states and props?

Comment: ofc, I will do it in a moment, I will edit my post. Sorry for polish names inside, but it shouldn't be the case.

Comment: I will add one more time - it all works fine, the case is just when I don't edit the date and it stays as defaultValue, it decrement the day by one. If I edit the date, all works fine.